# Increase UIButton's touch effect radius on highlight

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa, uibutton

Is there a way to increase UIButton's "glow effect" when `Shows Touch on Highlight` is enabled? In most of the cases it's fine on the iPhone, but way too small on the iPad. If it's not possible, any ideas how to achieve the desired behavior?

**EDIT:**

Basically, I'm looking for how to subclass UIButton to add this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use something like this:
Add a target for button pressed on your button.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Here's the method that gets invoked when the button is pressed. You can change the shadowRadius to fit your needs.

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    DDLogInfo(@"%@ Button Pressed...", button.titleLabel.text);
    UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    button.layer.shadowColor = [color CGColor];
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0f;
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which imitates the exact same (animated) behaviour, but with an assignable radius. Your code also fails if I want to use shadow at the same time.

Comment: Am actually not using "Shows touch on highlight" instead doing my own highlight where I can adjust the radius.

Comment: Remove the last line from my solution: button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: This is not exactly what I've wanted. Meanwhile I was able to find a proper solution which I can't post here because of privacy reasons. Thus, I accept your answer which is also good enough.

Comment: @AttilaH Have you find the solution for the showtouchonHighlight?

Comment: The radius can't be adjusted. I ended up subclassing `UIButton` and overriding `setHighlighted:`.

Answer (score -1):

You could create an image of the glow effect and add that to the button when its highlighted.

Comment: Then, how could I assign the radius? How is it going to be animated?