# showsTouchWhenHighlighted to large size UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to add the showsTouchWhenHighlighted effect to UIButton.

```
loveitbtn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
```

I have used above line to implement this effect. But when I click on button it is showing the highlighted effect to very small area not to whole button. 
[image]
Can we set this effect to whole button? If someone has any idea please help me out.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Try https://github.com/lightroomapps/LRGlowingButton, I haven't used it, but let me know if it worked for u or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to control the built-in control for the highlighting.

You may refer to this post for the work around by setting the button's white shadow using QuartzCore (you will need to include QuartzCore header and library):
[Increase UIButton's touch effect radius on highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481928/increase-uibuttons-touch-effect-radius-on-highlight)